# how to get client pc configuration from website

Tags: java, php, jquery, asp.net, actionscript-3

Is there any option to get client PC hardware configuration from a website? I need to create a website for showing the local system configuration. I know there are many tools to get system configuration. But the user want to get them PC configuration from a website. I tried in many ways.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't get client PC configuration from web, the only way is to ask the user to do that, or may be, using an executable tool at client PC, that's not recommended.

Comment: @dlyaza is there any plugins available for that?

Comment: Computer configurations cannot be get using the web technology such as PHP or ASP or Similar. What you can do is to develop a plugin or software similar to "Dell System Detect". It is a small .exe file which runs in the client system, analyzes the system and sends to configuration details back to the website.

Comment: @Surya Thankyou for Sharing Your Ideas. I Will Try in this way

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access computer information from a browser, and especially not php. Php is a server-side script that runs on the server and therefore cannot access information about the client that isn't first sent to the server.

The way to accomplish your goal of retrieving PC hardware information is to develop an application that the user can download and run that gathers and sends the desired information to your server.

Comment: is there any plugins available for get the configuration from client?

Comment: depends what plugin you're looking for. You might be able to develop a plugin for the user's browser that they can install. But within your control (server, javascript, etc) no there's no plugin that will give you access to client hardware information. It's a security/privacy issue.

Comment: Am Looking for Browser plugins. or any other possible to show client system Configuration without any tools. can request the user to add browser plugins.

Comment: Yea but there's no guarantee they'll add them